# docker-sync issue: my updates for source code are not visible on the browser

Tags: docker

[this is my docker-compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtXJx.png)After running my images in Docker and running `docker-sync`, I'm unable to see my updates for the source code on the browser. This is a part of the results of the command docker-sync start. I got an error.

```
copying    optimize transfers using local copies (default true)

    message  unison: unknown option '-v'. 
    success  Unison server started 
    command  docker inspect --format='{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "5000/tcp") 0).HostPort}}' unison-sync  
    command  unison -ignore='Name .git' -ignore='Name .idea' -ignore='Name node_modules' '/c/Users/Mourtada/Desktop/CRM-APP/moenn-security-app'   
-auto -batch -prefer '/c/Users/Mourtada/Desktop/CRM-APP/moenn-security-app'   
-copyonconflict -v socket://127.0.0.1:52852
      error  Error starting sync, exit code 0 
    message  Usage: unison [options] 
   or unison root1 root2 [options] 
   or unison profilename [options]
```

Comment: A cursory glance shows you might be running in an emulated environment (WSL), or might have an issue with your volume mounts. `-v` error. 

Challenging to troubleshoot without knowing a bit more about your environment.. Try sharing your docker-compose files, or giving more info about your environment.

Comment: im working on windows 10 OS , i use docker desktop to build and run my images , and i use a app which i installed from Microsoft store te execute Linux commands (Debian) to run docker-sync. and i got the error i shared when i executed docker-sync start and im still not seeing any modifications in the browser when i change my frontend m ysource code

Comment: version: "3.4"
services:
 #this is my docker-compose.yml file 

  node_frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      target: moenn_security_frontend_angular
    # depends_on:
    #   - php
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/docker/node_angular/logs:/root/.npm/_logs
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/app:rw
    ports:
      - '4202:4200'

  

volumes:
  php_socket:
  db_data:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config: